# Will using git config --global change the settings of pre-existing git repositories?

Tags: git, version-control

Let's say I make a repo

```
cd repo1
git init
git config user.name "Jack"
git config user.email jack@hill.com
```

and then I make another

```
cd ../repo2
git init
git config --global user.name "Jill"
git config --global user.email jill@hill.com
```

Will I be Jack or Jill in repo1?
I assume that I'll be Jack in repo1 if these 2 steps are done in the opposite order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be Jack in `repo1`, and Jill in `repo2`, regardless of the order in which you run the commands. From the `git config` man page:

```
   If not set explicitly with --file, there are four files where git config will search for configuration options:

   $GIT_DIR/config
       Repository specific configuration file.

   ~/.gitconfig
       User-specific configuration file. Also called "global" configuration file.

   $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config
       Second user-specific configuration file. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not set or empty, $HOME/.config/git/config will be used. Any single-valued variable
       set in this file will be overwritten by whatever is in ~/.gitconfig. It is a good idea not to create this file if you sometimes use older versions of
       Git, as support for this file was added fairly recently.

   $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig
       System-wide configuration file.
```

Git loads these files in that order. Your local repository's, `.git/config`, takes precedent over `~/.gitconfig`, which takes precedent over `$HOME/.config/git/config`, which takes precedent over `/etc/gitconfig`. Moreover:

```
All writing options will per default write to the repository specific configuration file. Note that this also affects options like --replace-all and
--unset. git config will only ever change one file at a time.
```

The `--global` flag doesn't change every `.git/config` on your system, just `~/.gitconfig`.